# Rhub CRAN check keeps giving HTML note on Fedora test - no command 'tidy' found

Tags: html, r, cran, tidy

I'm developing an R package to be uploaded to CRAN and I keep getting a NOTE when I run

```
devtools::check_rhub()
```

The results I'm getting are:

```
> On fedora-clang-devel (r-devel)
checking HTML version of manual . . . NOTE
Skippping checking HTML validation: no command 'tidy' found
```

I keep trying to fix it but I'm not sure of where the problem is... also, it runs fine on Windows and Ubuntu.

Does anyone know what I should do? Or is it possible that CRAN will ignore this note?

Thanks in advance.

I tried fixing it by checking for any HTML code that I had, but deleted those.

I tried updating HTML Tidy on my macOS to the newest version, but also nothing changed.

I expect to figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 6):

This NOTE refers to a piece of system software that is missing on the test platform. You can't fix it by updating any system tools on your **local** system, as that's not where the problem is. Someone (possibly you?) has [already posted an issue on Github](https://github.com/r-hub/rhub/issues/548), which is the correct place to follow up.

This NOTE should not be a problem for CRAN submission; the only issue is that your HTML is not being validity-checked on Fedora. Presumably any validity problems will be discovered when the HTML is checked on other platforms; the only (unlikely) edge case would be where you have HTML generated by your package that for some reason would fail validity checks **only** on Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on Windows and fixed it by installing the latest version of Rtools (specific for R Devel 4.3). Not sure if Linux uses Rtools or simply has the included programs already installed, but perhaps updating any Linux programs that correspond to the Rtools programs might help.